# What kind of multi-threading conflicts/deadlocks can occur in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading

The known danger of multi-threading in android is accessing UI from another thread. But what other types of conflicts can occur in Android. Is it possible to have a deadlock using looper and handler? If so, how could this occur? Frankly I have not experienced deadlocks in Android, but I keep getting this question from folks, and don't really know how to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Bugs related to multithreading such as deadlocks and race conditions are no different on Android than other platforms. Giving you an exhaustive list of these problems and possible solutions is beyond the scope of this web site due to the necessary background you need to acquire.
The following URLs might answer your question:

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/avoid-these-java-threading-gotchas/

https://tudorturcu.wordpress.com/2013/05/15/some-multi-threading-gotchas/